# Parent text with child content in the middle of it

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have this XML code

```
<parag>blah blah blah</parag>
<parag>blah blah, refer to <linkCode code1="a" code2="b" code3="c"/> for further details.</parag>
```

I can't figure out how to get the link to stay in the middle of the parent text. The following code

```
<xsl:for-each select="parag">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="linkCode">
            <a href="file-{@code1}-{@code2}-{@code3}.html">this link</a>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

produces

```
<p>blah blah blah</p>
<p>blah blah, refer to for further details.<a href="file-a-b-c.html">this link</a></p>
```

What I want is

```
<p>blah blah blah</p>
<p>blah blah, refer to <a href="file-a-b-c.html">this link</a> for further details.</p>
```

Any ideas? No, I don't have control over the content of the XML.

Answer (score 1):

**Use just simple overriding of the identity rule**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="linkCode">
   <a href="file-{@code1}-{@code2}-{@code3}.html">this link</a>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="parag">
   <p><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided fragment wrapped into a single top element -- to get a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <parag>blah blah blah</parag>
    <parag>blah blah, refer to <linkCode code1="a" code2="b" code3="c"/> for further details.</parag>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
    <p>blah blah, refer to <a href="file-a-b-c.html">this link</a> for further details.</p>
</t>
```

**And if you want to have the top element not output**:

just add this template:

```
 <xsl:template match="/*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
```

**So, the complete code becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="linkCode">
   <a href="file-{@code1}-{@code2}-{@code3}.html">this link</a>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="parag">
   <p><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></p>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```